# iis replaces url with strange pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, intranet

i am building a web api and everything works fine on my localhost iis express.

But when i publish my application to my normal iis, the iis replaces a part of the url with a strange pattern that i have never seen before

This leads to an 404 error everytime, cause the IIS replace the link in every browser!

why is that?

IIS Express API Link:

http://intranet-bla/crmServer/crmGet/getSomeThing?id=1978338358

IIS API Link:

http://intranet-bla/crmServer/**(S(nsz24dspha255yzcyy2c4eqh))**/crmGet/getSomeThing?id=1978338358

**EDIT:**

*The 404 Error was gone after renaming the http-handler, the strange url is still there but isnt a issue anymore*

Comment: It almost looks like cookieless sessions is turned on in the web.config or there is some other pre-processor. I don't believe this will be related to your app and is most likely something already setup on that server.

Comment: As mark says, this issue is related with the server config.Could you please share the details webconfig you have used in the IIS's api application? This will help us find the issue.